# issue opening jquery ui dialog inside css lightbox

Tags: css, jquery-ui, lightbox

I found a good lightbox effect on a blog but I'm not sure how to tweak it the way I need. Aside from manipulating background `opacity` and `z-index`, it works by setting a divs css display property to "none" and then "block" when the effect is triggered. In that div I have the unordered lists I apply the jquery `menu()` and `dialog()` methods to. The lightbox effect and the ui methods work, but the dialog won't open inside the div designated by the class: "white content". It opens behind the white content instead. I tried to change the z-index of the dialog() in my script, but it didn't work.  below I have the code from my `.css`, `.html` and `.js` files.

CSS

```css
/*Lightbox effect
----------------------------------*/
.black_overlay {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0%;
            left: 0%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 2000%;
            background-color: black;
            z-index:1001;
            -moz-opacity: 0.8;
            opacity:.80;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.white_content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 25%;
            left: 25%;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: white;
            z-index:1002;
            overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML

```html
<body>

  <div id="light" class="white_content">

<div id="dialog" title="Invite">

<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="ageGroup">Age Group</a>
            <ul>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">18-21</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">21-30</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">30-40</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">40-50</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">50-60</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">60-70</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">70-80</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">80-90</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">90-100</a></li>
            </ul>

    </li>
    </ul>

    <button>Button label</button>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>

</body>
```

JS

```js
$(function(){

//event handler that triggers lightbox effect 

    $('#list').on('click', '.edit', function(event){

        //this is where the lightbox effect executes. 

        $("#light").css("display", "block");
        $("#fade").css("display", "block");

//I want the dialog and menu to open inside of the div #light

        $("#dialog").dialog();


        $(".menu").menu();// closes $("menu").menu() 


     $( "button" ).button();

     }//closes function(event)

);// closes on()


}); //closes $function.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to get a UI dialog to open inside a `<div>`. Might be that it is made purposely to always open as a child of `<body>`. In jQuery UI site the dialog runs inside a `<iframe>` so that might trick you to believe it's inside a `<div>`.

My suggestion would be to put jQuery UI components inside your lightbox as it is already kind of like a dialog. Also if you want your lightbox to move you should be good with jQuery UI's [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/).

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/UkpeV/5/) a jsFiddle I made to explain what I'm after.

Comment: wow jsFiddle is great. Thanks so much for taking the time to do that.